# In Java, Is it possible to concatenate the value of a variable into a variable name (Sounds messed up, but please read details)

Tags: java, variables, naming-conventions, concatenation, declaration

Basically I have a variable, zlort = one;

I want to concatenate the value of zlort into a variable (object reference) name.

Like

```
BankAccount Accountzlort = new BankAccount;
```

I want the zlort in Account.zlort to actually be the replaced with value of zlort (one--meaning I want the value to be Accountone), and not zlort itself.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Might I ask, what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Basically I have a user controlled loop (with a sentinel). The loop creates an object and supplies it with method parameters that the user provides. I have considered using an array for each object, but our teacher specifically told us that we cannot use arrays yet.

Comment: What are you doing with the objects (after the loop)? If your teacher doesn't want you to use arrays yet, maps probably aren't acceptable either.

Comment: +8 for one answer and +15 for total answers, yet 0 for the question. I always find that disturbing.

Comment: Basically a user has a list of values from a database-like table. The user is supposed to enter each entry using keyboard input and tell the loop when to stop. Our teacher told us to create an object for each entry the user provides and change the fields using mutator methods to values that the user provides as well. The problem I am facing is being able to create a new object reference name each time I go through the loop.

Comment: If you don't have to do anything with the objects after the loop stops then you probably don't need a different reference for each object.

Comment: I need to use each object afterwards through a loop. I have to display their fields using methods.

Comment: So your program goes like this: Loop{ Collect input, create objects, modify fields} THEN Loop{ Display information about objects }?  --Or-- does it do this: Loop { Collect input, create objects, modify fields, display information }

Comment: The former is correct. I would output the fields in a separate loop--after the user has finished inputting the information in the first loop and decides to terminate it.

Comment: And your teacher doesn't want you to use arrays? Have you been taught any data structures (such as a list or as below, a map) yet?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that the teacher said we should put each object in an ArrayList object after creating them. However, he said we cannot use traditional arrays.

Comment: Aha!!! Well, the `ArrayList` solution makes it much easier =) You create an `ArrayList<BankAccount>` before the first loop, and each time you finish making a new `BankAccount` in the loop, call the `ArrayList`'s `add()` method (which will add the `BankAccount` to the end of the `ArrayList`). Then in your other loop you will want to loop over each element of the `ArrayList` and display the information for each one. Try it out, and if you need help implementing it, post a response and I'll put up a better response in an answer later tonight (away for a few hours). Good luck!

Comment: Can I have multiple BankAccount instances with the same name then? : ) That would solve my problem so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the explanations in your comments, the fact that you can't use an array but  can use an `ArrayList'...

Rather than creating a new variable name (or array element, or map value) for each `BankAccount`, you can probably use scope to your advantage.

**Scope** is the concept that a reference to a variable only has meaning within a certain part of code. If you declare a variable inside a method, that variable can only be seen within that method. A variable declared within a **[block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)** (a loop, if statement, etc ) can only be seen from within that block.

Class fields have a different kind of scoping that can be adjusted with keywords (**[see here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)**).

For example:

```
public class ScopeExample

    int classInt = 10;

    public void method() {
        int methodInt = 0; // This integer can only be seen by code in 
                           // this method
    }

    public void method2() {
        //doSomething(methodInt) // This line won't compile because i is 
                                 // declared in a different method!
        doSomething(classInt); // This line will compile and work 
                               // because x is declared in the class that 
                               // contains this method.
        int index = 0;
        while (index < 3) {
            int whileInt = index; // This integer can only be seen from within 
                                  // this while loop! It is created each 
                                  // loop iteration.
            doSomething(whileInt);
        }
        doSomething(whileInt); //This line won't work, whileInt is out of scope!
    }

    public doSomething(int a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

SO! If you create a `BankAccount` object within the loop, you don't have to worry about creating a new name for the next one. Each time the loop iterates it will become a new object (when you create it).

If you have to store it, you definitely will need to use an array or other data structure (`ArrayList`!).

Building on the idea of scope, you -can- have the same variable name for each new `BankAccount`. A variable reference name isn't guaranteed to be paired with the object that it refers to. That is a convenience to the programmer, so you don't have to know the exact memory address it is being stored in.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object o;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        Object reference = new Object(); // Create a new Object and store 
                                         // it in 'reference'
        o = obj; // The Object 'o' now refers to the object in 'reference'
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(o); // This should print information about the 
                           // LAST object created.
}
```

The new `Object` created in the loop does not **belong** to 'obj'. You as a programmer use 'obj' to point to the `Object`. The program doesn't really know what obj means, other than the fact that it points to the Object you just `created`.

Finally, you can use this along with an `ArrayList` to make your life easier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Our new ArrayList to hold our objects!
    ArrayList<Object> stuff = new ArrayList<Object>();

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        Object obj = new Object(); // Create an object and make obj point to it.
        stuff.add(obj); // Put "the object that 'obj' points to" in 'stuff'.
        i++;
    }

    // This loop goes through all of the Objects in the ArrayList and prints them
    for (int index = 0; index < stuff.size(); index++) {
        System.out.println(stuff.get(i)); // This will print a single 
                                          // object in the ArrayList each time.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

No you can't, but you might put the instance in a map:

```
Map<String,BankAccount> map = new HashMap<String,BankAccount>();
map.put("Account" + zlort, new BankAccount());
```

Comment: It would be better to avoid raw types by using `Map<String, BankAccount>`.

Comment: Reply updated using generics. Emmanuel is working on Apache Commons so he probably knows this.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean dynamically choosing the name to assign a variable to, then no.

You could use a `HashMap` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change the name of a variable at runtime. That would lead to extreme security and stability problems when dealing with any real-world application.

However, as the two answers here have mentioned, a `HashMap` might acheive what you are looking for. (See the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)!!)

A `HashMap` (or any other map, for that matter) maps a **Key** to a **Value**. The concept is similar to a variable, which is a **name** -> **value** mapping. The only difference is that variables are part of the actual program code, which is effectively unmodifiable after compiling. A `Map` is a data structure that can be modified by the running program. This allows you to freely add key-value pairings to it.

Note that in Java, type-safety is encouraged through the use of Generics. Basically this ensures that the key can only be of one type (e.g. `String`) and the value can be of only one type (`BankAccount`). A thorough coverage of Generics can be found [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

You would declare this as follows:

```
Map<String, BankAccount> accounts = new HashMap<String, BankAccount>();
```

And then to add a key-value pair to the map, you would use the `put()` method (which 'puts' a value into the map, associated with a key)

```
String key = "Key"
BankAccount value = new BankAccount();
accounts.put(key, value);
```

To retrieve it, you would use the `get()` method.

```
BankAccount retrievedValue;
retrievedValue = accounts.get(key);
```